# Can't acces cross-origin content on my Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

So I have a website that gets some content from a different website through API calls. I have enabled CORS configuration in my Amazon S3 bucket settings and added the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://mywebsite.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

However, browser feedback mentions that I have still not allowed cross origin. 
What have I forgotton in this configuration?

Comment: Two questions:

1) Are you accessing the website from the website in the allowed origin or from the different website you mentioned above? 

2) Where did you get the expose header value from? I couldn't see this in the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html). You issue might be from that. try removing it and see.

Comment: Hi @Abba ! Answering your questions: 1) I'm not completely understanding your question, but to clarify: my amazon website on S3 Bucket needs access to some json files. These json files are located on a different website. So: amazonwebsite1.com needs access from files from awebsitehostedbyme.com. 2) I found the expose header in [this part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) of the docs. I removed it but it didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake, but somehow think that I might not be the only one. So I'm gonna share what happened for those who come across the same problem.
If your **www.domain.com** needs to get some files or must do some API calls from **www.domain2.com**; then it is domain2 that must allow CORS and not the other way around.
www.domain.com <----- gets files <----- www.domain2.com (has Access-Control-Allow-Origin)
Because luckily the second domain is under my charge too, I simply added the following in my .htaccess:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```